# detect maps v2 zoom by user not device(automatic)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using the code below to detect zoom by user but its in loop even if I dont touch anything .How do I detect human touch on device and check if he zoomed ? I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

```
 googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if (position.zoom < 12 ) {
                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13));
                        }

                 googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                    }
                }

              });

    }
```

Comment: The third if-condition does not make much sense. It's the same as `position.zoom < 20´.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The endless loop is obvious.
Either you have a zoom level of 20, then you will always end up in the second if condition.
Or you have a zoom level less than 20, then you will always end up in the third if condition.

I would try something like this:

```
boolean changeTriggeredByProgram = false;
googleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition position) {
        if (changeTriggerByProgram) {
            changeTriggeredByProgram = false;
            return;
        }
        /* Check, whether you want to adapt the position by program, 
         * and if so, do the following: */
        changeTriggeredByProgram = true;
        googleMap.animateCamera(newPosition, new CancelableCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                changeTriggeredByProgram = false;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

No guarantee that this works. I am using a slightly different solution, as my problem is slightly different.

Comment: In my case newposition is current position and what does new CancelableCallback() do I never used it in my code and how do I use that w.r.t the above code I mentioned.The code does the following:   1. Tilt when completely zoomed  2.Deos not allow user to zoom above 12 . Please suggest if you know any other way to tackle the above 2 questions .Also please explain new CancelableCallback() .I really appreciate any help .Its not explained in any doc I have gone through .Thanks again.

Comment: The CancelableCallback detects, whether the animation finished completely, or whether it was canceled by user interaction or by starting another animation. By resetting the boolean inside onCancel() you know that the next call to onCameraChange was not a result of your own camera position change (which was canceled), but it was a change obviously triggered by the user. And only in this cases, I think, you will interfere and reduce the zoom if its greater than 12 or do whatever changes you want to do automatically.

Comment: I am confused can you edit the my code above please.It will be a great help.

Comment: Just insert your 3 if-conditions at the place where I put the comment "Check, whether you want to..." in the code snippet above. But inside your code only calculate the new position without directly sending it to the map (i.e. without calling animateCamera). The position will then be send to the map by the remainder of my code snippet.